# Why the Perpetual Virginity of Mary?

Tags: catholicism, soteriology, perpetual-virginity

The Savior having been born of a Virgin as prophesied, what if any, according to Roman Catholicism, are the salvific benefits of the continued or perpetual virginity of Mary?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/4423/23657

Comment: @ Kris No it didn't but I have re-asked the question for the sake of clarity.